# JPA unable to assign a new persisted entity in a many to one relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have to JPA Entities defined with a bidirectional relationship many to one, hereby:

```
@Entity
public class Department implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="DEPARTAMENTO_ID_GENERATOR",sequenceName="DEPARTAMENTO_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="DEPARTAMENTO_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="DEP_ID")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="DEP_DESC")
    private String desc;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Academico
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    private Set<Proffesor> proffesors;
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name="ACADEMICOS")
public class Proffesor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="ACADEMICOS_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="ACADEMICOS_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator="ACADEMICOS_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="ACD_ID")
    private long id;
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name="ACD_DEPADSCRITO_DEP")
    private Department department;
// getters and setters.
}
```

After in a transactional Spring service I have the next code to manipulate the entities in this way.

```
@Transactional (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void createDepartmentWithExistentProffesor(String desc,Long idAvaiableProf) {
        // new department   
        Department dep = new Department();
        dep.setDesc(desc);
        HashSet<Proffesor> proffesors = new HashSet<Proffesor>();
        dep.setProffesors(proffesors);


// I obtain the correct attached Proffesor entity
        Proffesor proffesor=DAOQueryBasic.getProffesorById(idAvaiableProf);

// I asign the relationship beetwen proffesor and department in both directions
                dep.addProffesors(proffesor);
// Persists department      
        DAODataBasic.insertDepartment(dep);
// The id value is not correct then Exception ORA-0221
        System.out.println("SERVICIO: Departamento creado con id: " + dep.getId());

    }
```

As I said in the comments the id of the new Department persisted is not a real database id inside the transaction, then it is produced an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
........

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02291: integrity restiction (HIBERNATE_PRB.FK_ACD2DEP) violated - primary key don't found
```

I've tried in a test, persist the new departmen entity with no relationship with Proffesor and I've seen that the id of the new department persisted entity has not a valid value inside the transaction but out of the transaction already the id has a correct value. 
But I need the correct value inside the transaction.

Can anybody help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="department",cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
private Set<Proffesor> proffesors;
```

Comment: have you tried merge professor in stead of persist new department. I know it does not make logical sense. but it worth giving it a go. After **Proffesor proffesor=DAOQueryBasic.getProffesorById(idAvaiableProf);** do this**proffesor.setDepartment(department);
entityManager.merge(professor);**
See if it would work.

Comment: Just before read your comment, I did it but doesn't work yet. Thanks for you help again.

Comment: Let's take a look. The SQL generated are correct. Select from Professor, Select from department (asigned to the professor), insert Department and update professor (to assign the new created department). In this last sentence is where takes place the integrity constraint violation, because the id of the new department does not exist in the data base. So the cascade policies are OK in my opinion but the id generated is missing? inside the current transaction.

Comment: Sorry the code above is a traslation from Spanish to English and I have made a mistake. professor is with 2 s not with 2 f as it was writen above. Sorry for my bad English use.

Comment: It was my fault. When I was describing the tables interactively, not DDL, the Oracle manager console created a trigger for insert operations, answer a new Id via sequence. Hence the principal key was not found for the child table. Disabling or deleting the trigger it works fine. >Thank you for you help.